# How can I log the information which NTv2 grid was used by gdal/ogr

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, ogr, gdalwarp

I am using gdal/ogr to transform my data from EPSG31467 to EPSG 25832.
I modified the epsg-string for EPSG 31467 so it uses a NTv2-grid ("BWTA2017.gsb").

```
<31467> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +nadgrids=@BWTA2017.gsb,@BETA2007.gsb,null +units=m +no_defs
```

Is it possible to log if gdal/ogr really used this NTV2-grid for transformations or if it used the two other options that were set as fallback-options ("Beta2007.gsb" or null)?

I want to be able to know **for each transformed file** if the provided NTv2-grid was used or less accurate parameters were used instead.

EDIT1: FME for example logs the objects that are outside the valid grid extent:

```
2018-03-01 13:35:35|  32.2|  7.1|WARN  |Coordinate (approx) 8E:47N outside grid file coverage; fallback used.
2018-03-01 13:36:00|  55.1| 22.9|WARN  |Coordinate (approx) 7E:47N outside grid file coverage; fallback used.
2018-03-01 13:36:05|  58.8|  3.7|WARN  |Coordinate (approx) 20E:60N outside grid file coverage; fallback used.
2018-03-01 13:36:05|  58.8|  0.0|WARN  |Coordinate (approx) 23E:62N outside grid file coverage; fallback used.
2018-03-01 13:36:05|  58.8|  0.0|WARN  |Coordinate (approx) 172E:10N outside grid file coverage; fallback used.
2018-03-01 13:36:05|  58.8|  0.0|WARN  |Coordinate (approx) 63E:42N outside grid file coverage; fallback used.
2018-03-01 13:36:05|  58.8|  0.0|WARN  |Coordinate (approx) 44E:70N outside grid file coverage; fallback used.
2018-03-01 13:36:05|  58.8|  0.0|WARN  |Coordinate (approx) 51E:123N outside grid file coverage; fallback used.
2018-03-01 13:36:05|  58.8|  0.0|WARN  |Coordinate (approx) 96E:9999S outside grid file coverage; fallback used.
```

Comment: If you use gdal command line tools you can try to add `--debug on` to the command and see if iy lists more info.

Comment: I already use --debug but there is no information which grid is used

Comment: Run the command specifying "none" then just with beta2007.gsb and then with just BWTA2017. Optionally, remove the grid files you don't want to be used. Are they the same or different? If the data is raster, you could pull a set of test points and convert those--it will be easier to see differences.

Comment: This would work for single files but I have to transform several thousands of Shapefiles and Geotiffs

Comment: Yes, it would work for single files, that's the point. You run a test on a few files. If there are any differences, you might assume the correct grid was used and run the transform on the rest of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting PROJ_DEBUG=on env variable? It works with cs2cs and shows details, e.g. on shift files used. Not sure how to get its output through GDAL/OGR. Maybe in addition to --debug on.

Update: ogr2ogr outputs the proj debug messages when --debug ON is used:

```
....
NTv2 - loading grid DHDN90
pj_open_lib(BWTA2017.gsb): call fopen(/usr/share/proj//BWTA2017.gsb) - succeeded
...
```